# Onclick redirect to https

Tags: javascript, html, https

I've updated a large(ish) website with a https certificate. Due to the amount of traffic coming from Google, I've currently only applied https to new pages (I'm planning a gradual transition - I don't want traffic to plummet while it is reindexed). The problem is there is a login form on every page.

Is there a way I can add javascript (either inline or otherwise) so that if the page is not https, 'onclick' (the following fields) directs to the https version of login.php?

```
type="password" name="login_password" id="navbar_password"
type="text" name="login_username" id="navbar_username"
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Kind Regards,

S.C>

Comment: not sure but wouldn't be a general redirect, till the change is done, be the easiest way to handle it? That way you don't have different behaviours on different pages of your website.

Comment: @Pete Many thanks for the reply. This is only a temporary measure while gradually changing over. Some of our older contents gets huge amounts of search engine traffic so I'm erring on the side of caution. All new pages are https and canonical to the https version. Older pages are still http and canonical to the http version. Server side 301's and html canonical tags are in place for the changes that have already been made :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can check if user currently uses non-https version and redirect him if needed when the input gets focus, just like you asked.

In HTML

```
<input type="text" name="login_username" id="navbar_username" 
onfocus="checkRedirect();">
```

In JS

```
function checkRedirect() {
  if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
    // is not https version
    window.location.replace('https://your-https-domain.com/');
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was not whether you hate a redirect or not.

Comment: What is wrong with you? I would not do it like OP but it was his question.
But let me know if you get the amount of users who don't use my sites.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies, especially @MaKobi

Comment: @Pete (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) Very mature... First be rude, then delete your comments. Wow.

Comment: Opps, that just posted by accident. This is only a temporary measure, and only on older contents which get lots of traffic. It will eventually be changed, but I don't want a huge break in traffic by doing all pages at the same time. Redirects on older contents isn't so much of a problem for users. All main pages and newer contents is already secured. There is no https issues for users that are logged in, only for guests. I understand your reply @Pete but it's literally to cover security while moving over to https :)

Comment: oh, your comments have gone @Pete :( I didn't take offence, everyone has different opinions

Comment: Thank you @MaKobi. Unfortunately I can't up-vote because I dont have enough rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to reach that:

1) AJAX call `onclick` action

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        /* this.responseText */
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", "https://your.domain.com/login.php");
xhr.send({ username: "foo", password: "bar" });
```

[More AJAX details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

2) Absolute form action URL

```
<form method="POST" action="https://your.domain.com/login.php">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't up-rate because I dont have enough rep :)

Comment: That's ok dude :)